# Why does lubridate appear to change time zones for two dates combined into a vector?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am seeing an unexpected result when using the lubridate package in R. I am simply trying to combine two dates into a vector. When I do so, the time zone changes. What is happening here?

```
> x <- ymd("2016-02-08")
> y <- ymd("2016-03-29")
> x
[1] "2016-02-08 UTC"
> y
[1] "2016-03-29 UTC"
> c(x,y)
[1] "2016-02-07 18:00:00 CST" "2016-03-28 19:00:00 CDT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `c()` will remove the timezone attribute. Hence you have to reassign it:

```
xy <- c(x,y)
attr(xy, "tzone") <- "UTC"
> xy
[1] "2016-02-08 UTC" "2016-03-29 UTC"
```

Source and more information: [Peter Ehlers on R Help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/lubridate-concatenation-issue-td4649697.html#a4649702)